# Bootstrap's Grid Row's Width is Overflowing

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I didn't even use CSS, only Bootstrap 5 included.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Bootstrap</title>
    <article>
      <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
      />

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="bs-justify.css" />

      <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
      ></script>
      <script
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
      ></script>
      <script
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
      ></script>
    </article>
  </head>
  <body>

        <br>
      <h4 class="display4 text-center"><i>The Grid System</i></h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 bg-dark text-light border">This is a 4 unit column</div>
            <div class="col-4 bg-dark text-light border">This is a 4 unit column</div>
            <div class="col-4 bg-dark text-light border">This is a 4 unit column</div>
            <div class="col bg-dark text-light border text-center">This is an automatic unit</div>
            <div class="col bg-dark text-light border text-right">This is an automatic unit</div>
            <div class="col bg-dark text-light border text-left">This is an automatic unit</div>
            <div class="col bg-dark text-light border">This is an automatic unit</div>
        </div>
        <br>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please help me guys. I am a beginner student btw.

I tried several things and it worked, but that's not the idea. The idea is why Bootstrap's default settings create overflowing width by default?

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.
The same is true for `<link>`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `.row` element in either a `.container` or `.container-fluid` element to achieve bootstrap's grid. For more info see [Bootstrap's Grid system docs page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/): *"Bootstrap’s grid system uses a series of containers, rows, and columns to layout and align content."*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Bootstrap</title>
    <article>
      <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
      />

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="bs-justify.css" />

      <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
      ></script>
      <script
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
      ></script>
      <script
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
      ></script>
    </article>
  </head>
  <body>

        <br>
      <h4 class="display4 text-center"><i>The Grid System</i></h2>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 bg-dark text-light border">This is a 4 unit column</div>
            <div class="col-4 bg-dark text-light border">This is a 4 unit column</div>
            <div class="col-4 bg-dark text-light border">This is a 4 unit column</div>
            <div class="col bg-dark text-light border text-center">This is an automatic unit</div>
            <div class="col bg-dark text-light border text-right">This is an automatic unit</div>
            <div class="col bg-dark text-light border text-left">This is an automatic unit</div>
            <div class="col bg-dark text-light border">This is an automatic unit</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p class="py-3 text-center">OR full-width container:</p>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 bg-dark text-light border">This is a 4 unit column</div>
            <div class="col-4 bg-dark text-light border">This is a 4 unit column</div>
            <div class="col-4 bg-dark text-light border">This is a 4 unit column</div>
            <div class="col bg-dark text-light border text-center">This is an automatic unit</div>
            <div class="col bg-dark text-light border text-right">This is an automatic unit</div>
            <div class="col bg-dark text-light border text-left">This is an automatic unit</div>
            <div class="col bg-dark text-light border">This is an automatic unit</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
  </body>
</html>
```